# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what(): basic_string::substr: __pos (which is 1) > this->size() (which is 0)

Tags: c++

I'm essentially a complete beginner to c++ as I only even finished Bucky's C++ tutorial yesterday. The program is supposed to cout the japanese/chinese characters and than the user enters text that corresponds to the string. I'm not getting any compilation errors, however whenever I try to run this I get the error that is in the title. When I run this I get the error terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what():  basic_string::substr: __pos (which is 1) > this->size() (which is 0). I've looked up other people with this problem stackoverflow.com/questions/27222447/stdout-of-range-what-basic-stringsubstr-pos and others, however I do not understand the answers provided as it is directed towards their code and I'm very new. 
Code:

```
                    #include <iostream>
                      #include "Values.h"
                         #include <fstream>
              #include <string>
                     #include <cstdlib>
                     #include <ctime>
                   using namespace std;
                     void Wrong();
                   void start();
                   void Correct();
                   string top;
                   string book;
                   string fish;
                   string umbrella;
                   string dictionary;
                   string sea;
                   string person;
                   string green;
                   string morning;
                   string school;
                   string water;
                   string dog;
                   string cat;
                   string weather;
                   string homework;
                   string bookstore;
                           string CurrentWord;

                   int main(){

                       ofstream nihon("Words.txt");

                      string top = "Pronounciation:    Meaning:    Hiragana:   Kanji:";
                       string book("\nHon                Book        ほん         本"); //1
                       string fish("\nSakana             Fish        さかな        魚"); //2
                       string umbrella("\nKasa               Umbrella    かさ         傘"); //3
                       string dictionary("\nJisho              Dictionary  じしょ        辞書");
                       string sea("\nUmi                Sea         うみ         海");
                       string person("\nHito               Person      ひと         人");
                       string green("\nMidori             Green       みどり        緑");
                       string morning("\nAsa                Morning     あさ         朝");
                       string school("\nDaigaku            University  だいがく      大学");
                       string water("\nMizu               Water       みず         水");
                       string dog("\nInu                Dog         いぬ         犬");
                       string cat("\nNeko               Cat         ねこ         猫");
                       string weather("\nTenki              Weather     てんき       天気"); //13
                       string homework("\nShukudai           Homework    しゅくだい     宿題");
                       string bookstore("\nHonya              Bookstore   ほんや       本屋");

nihon << top << book << fish << umbrella << dictionary << sea << person << green << morning << school << water << dog << cat << weather << homework << bookstore;
           // Nihon = Japan, Closing Nihon? :)
               nihon.close();
    string CurrentWord;
  /*   try
{
    throw 1;
}
catch (std::exception const &exc)
{
    std::cerr << "Exception caught " << exc.what() << "\n";
}
catch (...)
{
    std::cerr << "Unknown exception caught\n";
}*/

start();
return 0;
```

}

```
void Wrong(){
    cout << "You're answer is not correct :(" <<endl;
    start();
}

void start(){

    srand(time(0));
    int pRandomnumber = 1+(rand()%15);
    ifstream nihongolearn("Words.txt");
    switch(pRandomnumber){
    case 1:
                   CurrentWord = book;
                   break;
                           case 2:
                   CurrentWord = fish;
                   break;
                           case 3:
                   CurrentWord = umbrella;
                   break;
                           case 4:
                   CurrentWord = dictionary;
                   break;
                           case 5:
                   CurrentWord = sea;
                   break;
                           case 6:
                   CurrentWord = person;
                   break;
                           case 7:
                   CurrentWord = green;
                   break;
                           case 8:
                   CurrentWord = morning;
                   break;
                           case 9:
                   CurrentWord = school;
                   break;
                           case 10:
                   CurrentWord = water;
                   break;
                           case 11:
                   CurrentWord = dog;
                   break;
                           case 12:
                   CurrentWord = cat;
                   break;
                           case 13:
                   CurrentWord = weather;
                   break;
                           case 14:
                   CurrentWord = homework;
                   break;
                           case 15:
                   CurrentWord = bookstore;
                           }
                   string answer;
                   string huff = CurrentWord.substr(30, 49);
                   cout << "What does "<< huff << " Mean?" << endl;
                   cin >> answer;
                   string displayed = CurrentWord.substr(19, 30);
                           if(answer!=displayed){
                               Wrong();
                           }else{
                               Correct();
                           }
                       }

                       void Correct(){
                           cout << "You're answer is correct :D" << endl;
                     start();
                       }
```

Comment: *however I do not understand the answers provided* -- The error is as straightforward as you can get.  Do you understand *why* you're getting this error?  Start with the "why" first, then work on "how to fix" second.

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially trying to extract substrings from empty strings.

This happens because your main function is not initializing the variables at global scope.

Instead, it constructs local variables, which  will not be visible outside of the main function.

When `start` is called, it accesses the global variables (still untouched, and therefore empty) and crashes.

I suggest you further your knowledge of C++ variable scoping rules in order to fully understand your mistake.

A simple solution is to stop constructing shadow variables for your strings in your main function, and simply assign the existing global variables, instead.

Answer (score 0):

First of, you are declaring string `top` globally (at the top), and then inside `main()` you are declaring a local variable named the same `top`. The one that has the content is the local. I suggest you move your string assignments at the very top like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
void Wrong();
void start();
void Correct();
string top  = "Pronounciation:    Meaning:    Hiragana:   Kanji:";
string book = "\nHon                Book        ほん         本";
string fish = "\nSakana             Fish        さかな        魚";
string umbrella = "\nKasa               Umbrella    かさ         傘";
string dictionary = "\nJisho              Dictionary  じしょ        辞書";
string sea = "\nUmi                Sea         うみ         海";
string person = "\nHito               Person      ひと         人";
string green = "\nMidori             Green       みどり        緑";
string morning = "\nAsa                Morning     あさ         朝";
string school = "\nDaigaku            University  だいがく      大学";
string water = "\nMizu               Water       みず         水";
string dog = "\nInu                Dog         いぬ         犬";
string cat = "\nNeko               Cat         ねこ         猫";
string weather = "\nTenki              Weather     てんき       天気";
string homework = "\nShukudai           Homework    しゅくだい     宿題";
string bookstore = "\nHonya              Bookstore   ほんや       本屋";
string CurrentWord;
```

Also, when using substr(), make sure string has enough characters to avoid this error. In your code you use it twice

```
string huff = CurrentWord.substr(30, 49);
string displayed = CurrentWord.substr(19, 30);
```

The first one, starts at position 30 and requires 49 characters from there, this means you will require (30+49 characters in the string) to prevent any error.

The string that `CurrentWord` will contain in your code, are between 42-43 characters total. So it is obviously out of the range.

```
                  string top =          "Pronounciation:    Meaning:    Hiragana:   Kanji:";
                   string book(         "\nHon                Book        ほん         本"); //1
                   string fish(         "\nSakana             Fish        さかな        魚"); //2
                   string umbrella(     "\nKasa               Umbrella    かさ         傘"); //3
                   string dictionary(   "\nJisho              Dictionary  じしょ        辞書");
                   string sea(          "\nUmi                Sea         うみ         海");
                   string person(       "\nHito               Person      ひと         人");
                   string green(        "\nMidori             Green       みどり        緑");
                   string morning(      "\nAsa                Morning     あさ         朝");
                   string school(       "\nDaigaku            University  だいがく      大学");
                   string water(        "\nMizu               Water       みず         水");
                   string dog(      "\nInu                Dog         いぬ         犬");
                   string cat(      "\nNeko               Cat         ねこ         猫");
                   string weather(      "\nTenki              Weather     てんき       天気"); //13
                   string homework(     "\nShukudai           Homework    しゅくだい     宿題");
                   string bookstore(    "\nHonya              Bookstore   ほんや       本屋");
```

I suggest changing the second parameter, only ask for 7 characters or so so it doesn't run out of the string. Also consider that \n may count as one or two characters depending on the system.

```
string huff = CurrentWord.substr(30, 7);
string displayed = CurrentWord.substr(19, 7);
```